# Views sort for right to left language

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

The titles of my nodes in Drupal 7 contain Urdu langugage (RTL) content. I have created a glossary view using Views module.

The alphabets of Urdu language are not in right order as they are in the original language.

For example, 
(س (1) | ش (1) | ص (1) | ض (1) | ٹ (1) | پ (2) | چ (1) | ڈ (1

How do I fix sorting for View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. At least not in Views. That's not the task of the client, that's the task of the server. Set a proper collation for the column and / or table. If you really wanted to, you can write a sort handler to use [`ORDER BY collation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) but changing the collation with [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is the right thing to do.

Comment: Awesome, I went to phpMyAdmin, opened up the table, and changed collation of the field in question. It seems to be fixed right now, but I have to wait until I add entries for all the alphabets. Thank you.